# changing the general theme of math fonts

Tags: fonts, math-mode, packages, amsmath

I'm using latex templates which is producing a particular kind of math font, shown below.

[image]

How can I change it to produce something like following? I'm particularly interested in changing the math font.

[image]

Is there any specific package that I should exclude? unfortunately there are a couple of style and cls files and I'm not sure what is responsible for this change in font.

Comment: The latter is the standard Computer Modern, it looks like. You need to produce a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to help us help you.

Comment: The math font you currently have looks like Euler.

Comment: I noticed that the second one is normal, but the problem is that I don't know where to look to bring this whole template back to normal. I'm using the MIT thesis template from [this git repo](https://github.com/mravanba/mit-phd-thesis) and I doing a quick search I couldn't find the term `Euler` anywhere. Did I miss it?

Comment: Edit: ChrisS: you were right. I was able to find `\usepackage[small]{eulervm}` and by commenting it out the problem was solved. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the template itself then write before `\begin{document}`:

```
\usepackage{kpfonts}
```

for Palatino like fonts or

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

for Computer Modern fonts.

Comment: The first solution clashes with the current setting (`LaTeX Error: Option clash for package textcomp.`) but the second one works. Any suggestion as why one may be better than the other?

Comment: @Siamak As I've already mentioned, you have to provide a MWE.

Comment: @Svend, as @ChrisS pointed out the problem was a the eulervm package. By removing it the problem was fix. Although just including the `usepackage{lmodern}` just before the begining of the document also did the trick.

Comment: @Siamak What has that got to do with the error you just mentioned?